# Splitting Qt forms between multiple ui files

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, user-interface, qt-designer

I have a main window UI file created in Qt Designer. To avoid clutter and make the code more modular I'd like to create some parts of this window in separate ui files.

For example I may have a tab widget on the main window and then I'd like to have separate page1.ui and page2.ui which I can then "embed" inside the main window.

Is it possible with just UI files or do I need to create a class for each additional widget?

I was thinking about creating separate classes `Page1UI` and `Page2UI` which publicly inherit from `ui_page1.h` and `ui_page2.h` generated by qmake (so that the widgets inside them can be easily accessed from the main window) and then promoting main window's placeholder widgets to those classes. So in code I'd have something like this for example:

```
connect (page1->ui->someButtonFromPage1uiFile, ..., this->ui->someMainWindowWidget, ...);
```

However Qt [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) doesn't seem to mention public inheritance so I wonder if this is the right approach or if there may be a simpler way.

Comment: you can use custom QWidgets in your ui by "promoting" a standard QWidget to the type you want to put in its place,

Comment: @ratchetfreak I said that in the question. I am wondering if a) I need to create a separate file for each UI file, or can I somehow embed them directly in each other; b) is public inheritance an OK approach to create my custom widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need inheritance for this. These UI files are just widgets. So of course you can do this. You should have a main class which will have a tab widget and then just add your page1, page2, etc in main tab widget. What you need is composition here in my opinion.

What you need to do is create a separate class derived from `QWidget` which will contain an object of your generated UI form. You need to call `setupUI()` of that generated form in your new class with `this` as parameter.

Comment: So technically, how do I promote one of main window's widgets to the other ui widget? Let's say I have a `form.ui` which generates `ui_form.h`. I've tried promoting a widget to `Ui_Form` class but I get several errors, stating that `Ui_Form` is not a `QWidget`.

Comment: @Marian I have added details in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So in my QWidget derived class should the UI form be a member or should I derive from it via public or private inheritance? Note that if I make it a private member I won't be able to access it from the main window class directly.

Comment: Its should be a memeber. I dont see any reason for private inheritance, It makes code less readable also. Add accesors for it so that you can access it in your main window.

Comment: Well Qt documentation itself suggests private inheritance, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.